# how do i move images from the usual left aligned to other areas of the html

Tags: html, css

This is the only way that I know how to display an image:

```
                <img src = "4_2915577.jpg"
                    alt = "Rex Sweezy"/>
```

But I am wondering if I can move the image to other areas of the browser (center, right-aligned)?

Comment: If you just put this question into Google instead you'd have an answer by now... https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=image+align+css+-w3schools

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ OP clearly doesn't have enough expertise to compose such search query. Nevertheless, the question is too broad and OP should get some basic understanding of HTML and CSS before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is change the align

```
<img src="radscout.gif" align="middle">
```

Answer (score 0):

In line:
    `<img src="4_2015577.jpg" style="text-align:center;" alt="Rex Sweezy"/>`

Embedded style sheet:

```
`<head>
  <style>
    img {text-align:center;}
  </style>
 </head>`
```

Or an external style sheet